# Rails AASM helper for links for which state it may go to. Prefix to method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, aasm

In AASM you can call the `may_run?` as in the example code in the AASM.

object:

```
class Job
  include AASM

  aasm do
    state :sleeping, :initial => true
    state :running, :cleaning

    event :run do
      transitions :from => :sleeping, :to => :running
    end

    event :clean do
      transitions :from => :running, :to => :cleaning
    end

    event :sleep do
      transitions :from => [:running, :cleaning], :to => :sleeping
    end
  end

end
```

Example

```
job = Job.new
job.sleeping? # => true
job.may_run?  # => true
job.run
job.running?  # => true
job.sleeping? # => false
job.may_run?  # => false
job.run       # => raises AASM::InvalidTransition
```

How do I create a helper which tests the `may_` for the action if I pass the object and the action in as parameters. Essentially I want to add a prefix to the method call using the helper similar to this:

```
def state_action_url(job, state)
   if job.may_state?
      #link_to action
   else
      #render disabled link text
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use smth like this:

```
def state_action_url(job, state)
   if job.public_send("may_#{state}?")
      #link_to action
   else
      #render disabled link text
   end
end
```